# Android - Looking for suggestion on creating a GridView programmatically resembling a spreadsheet?

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview, android-adapter

i have gotten started with the code below. Perhaps I had false ideas about what the GridView was going to give me..like being able to making a call to set up the header names for my columns, and just going through a loop assigning text to each row, column pair as i went through that loop. That is really all I am looking for.

I suppose I could make up my own GridView with a bunch of textviews with lines separating each row,column "cell" but I obviously misunderstood I guess on what GridView could do out of the box. Something exactly like what you would see in a spreadsheet with each cell separated by lines - and putting data in each cell.

Looking for suggestions on perhaps what kind of adapter is needed if I have to go that route?

```
   GridView grid = new GridView(this);

    grid.setId(ViewIdentification.getId());
    grid.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    grid.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    grid.setNumColumns(3);
    grid.setColumnWidth(GridView.AUTO_FIT);
    grid.setVerticalSpacing(5);
    grid.setHorizontalSpacing(5);
    grid.setStretchMode(GridView.STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am going to be creating my own LinearLayout of vertical and horizontal textboxes.